# When should I pass setting-like value as class' variable and when as an assoc. array?

Tags: coding-style, code-quality, class-design, variables

Following [my other question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/230111/57759), is there a general rule of thumb, when we should pass a setting-like value, that controls class' behavior (for example displayed texts) as as class' constant or variable, one-by-one, and when it is better to "pack" them to one associative array? Or is it just a choice of the developer?

For example -- is this approach better (PHP code):

```
class SomeClass
{
    public $errorIncorrectProtocol = 'Please, don't use GET protocol in this context!';
    public $errorMissingId = 'The ID can't be empty or equal zero...';
}
```

than this one:

```
class SomeClass
{
    public $errorMessages = array
    (
        'IncorrectProtocol'=>'Please, don't use GET protocol in this context!',
        'MissingId'=>'The ID can't be empty or equal zero...'
    );
}
```

and if yes -- then, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good practice here (in PHP at least) is to use a combination of constants and arrays. To follow your error messages example:

```
class SomeClass {
    const ERR_INCORRECT_PROTOCOL = "incorrectProtocol";
    const ERR_MISSING_ID = "missingId";

    public $errorMessages = array(
        self::ERR_INCORRECT_PROTOCOL => "Please, don't use GET protocol in this context!",
        self::ERR_MISSING_ID => "The ID can't be empty or equal zero..."
    );
}
```

Error messages can then easily be retrieved:

```
$someObj = new SomeClass();
$someObj->errorMessages[SomeClass::ERR_INCORRECT_PROTOCOL];
```

Generally speaking, I don't think having individual variables in this context provides any benefits over using a constants and arrays. Instead, it simply clutters the internals of your class, or worse (if they're publicly exposed) clutters your API and possibly confuses developers (what's this `errorMissingId`? Is it some error object? A string? Is it safe to change? Do I need it?)

Comment: Thanks for a great answer. Do you have any source of this "good practice"? I can't understand, how using extra constants for keys in assoc. array could benefit code or me?

Comment: I've never seen it written down, but I use it myself and I've seen it used in a number of large PHP projects too.